# Do i have to re-build my css files whenever i add a new class using tailwind css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I just started using tailwind today and i noticed that whenever i add new breakpoint prefix   "*e.g flex or text-3xl*"   it doesn't get applied to my css file until i rebuild the css again.

its' that how it's meant to be?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah same here, I guess it is meant to be like that since on the tailwindcss website, it mentions in the installation process to run "npx tailwindcss -i ... --watch" which means that it rebuilds everytime there is a change.

Why this is so? I have no idea, and will leave it to someone more experienced in this to answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32384349)